# git gui not showing untracked files

Tags: git, git-gui

For some reason, `git gui` is not showing any untracked files. This is happening in all repositories on this system.

I understand how `.gitignore` works, and have confirmed that is not the problem, because the same untracked files show up in `git status` just fine.

What's broken?

I'm using `git-gui version 0.12.0.64.g89d6` on CentOS 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with `git-gui`.

Whenever I have a global `excludesfile` specified, and that file exists, `git gui` seems to ignore *everything*, while `git` itself acts as it should.

**`~/.gitconfig`:**

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

and an empty `~/.gitignore` causes this behavior.